# Missing Files in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have a project which I can open on the computer which I created the project on.

However, when I upload it to Google Drive, download and unzip it onto a different computer, and open the project in Android Studio the only files which are appearing are Java files. See this screenshot:

[image]

Also, when I open the project in file explorer, this appears:

[image]

Does anyone have any advice on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the project the correct way.

```
Go to File->New->Import Project->Select your project
Choose Import from external model and select Gradle. Press Next.
Then make sure to select the correct location or gradle OR gradle wrapper.
Then press Finish.
```

Hope This works.